# How can I print this using for loops?

Tags: java

How can I print this using for loops?

```
     1
    22
   333
  4444
 55555
```

I have tried this. But it is not printing what I want to print.

```
public class void main(String[] args) {
int last = 5, first = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= last; i++) {
    for (int j = last; j > i; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int k = i; k >= 1; k--){
        System.out.print(k);
    }
    System.out.println();  
}
```

}

It just prints this.

```
     1
    21
   321
  4321
 54321
```

Comment: see my edit below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see the first time you print, it is correct, then is when `k` is equal to `i`, so just print `i`

```
System.out.print(i);
```

**edit**

As per your edited code, do my above change, plsu

```
for (int j = last; j > i; j--) {
```

**output**

```
    1
   22
  333
 4444
55555
```

**final**

```
    int last = 5;
    for (int i = 1; i <= last; i++) {
        for (int j = last; j > i; j--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = i; k >= 1; k--){
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        System.out.println();  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your new problem solution just change k into i System.out.print(i)

```
        int last = 5, first = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= last; i++) {
        for (int j = last; j > i; j--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = i; k >= 1; k--){
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Output:

```
       1
      22
     333
    4444
   55555
```

Comment: Hello. The main thing I want to achieve is to get spaces in front of 1. Like "    1" this. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Can u check what I posted again please? I edited it. Now it shows what I want to do.

Comment: @Edmund check .

Comment: @Edmund to become a good developer you should enhance your searching skills. :)

Answer (score 0):

In every loop the number of blanks before a given number i are maxNumber - i and the times the current number is displayed are i:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        String blanks = "";
        for (int j = 1; j <= 5-i; j++)
        {
            blanks += " ";
        }
        String number = "";
        for(int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
        {
            number += i;
        }
        System.out.print(blanks + number);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get working code, it's helpful to first describe the detailed solution in words. That might be:

- To print a triangle of height `height`, individually print each row from 1 to `n`.

  - To print a single row `row`, determine:

    - How many spaces it needs.
    - How many digits it needs.
    - Which digit to print.
    - The digit to print is the same as the row number `row`.
    - The number of digits `digits` is also the same as the row number `row`.
    - The number of spaces `spaces` depends on how long the line should be in total.
    - The number of spaces is `width - digits`.
    - To print a character repeatedly, use a `for` loop counting from 0 up to but excluding the repetition.

This description then translates into this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int height = 5;
    int width = height;   // can also be larger than height

    for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++) {
        int digit = row;
        int digits = row;
        int spaces = width - digits;

        for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < digits; i++) {
            System.out.print(digit);   // assuming that digit needs only a single character to print
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Sure, this program is longer than the other ones, but when stepping through it using a debugger, you have all the information about the current state captured in the variables. By looking at the variable values, you can always ask yourself: does it make sense, and do `spaces` and `digits` and `width` fit together?

This program also splits up the total work into two phases. In the first phase, determine what to print and how much, and then just print it.